# Eisenstein series with character

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I am currently following this course http://www.few.vu.nl/~sdn249/modularforms16/ from the University of Utrecht, and I am trying to solve problem 5.(a) from the 6th Homework Sheet.

Let $\chi$ be a primitive Dirichlet character modulo $N$, and let $\zeta$ be a $N$-th root of unity in $\mathbf{C}$. I am asked to show that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\chi(j)\frac{x+\zeta^j}{x-\zeta^j}=\frac{2N}{\tau(\overline{\chi})(x^N-1)}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\overline{\chi}(m)x^m\in\mathbf{C}[[x]].$$
As a hint, it says "compute the residues".

I am guessing it's because my Complex Analysis skills are quite rusty at this point, but I really don't see how to start proving this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The LHS is
$$F(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\chi(j)\frac{2\zeta^j}{x-\zeta^j}$$
so equals $g(x)/(x^n-1)$ where $g$ is a polynomial of degree $\le nN-1$.
This polynomial will be characterised by
$$2\chi(j)\zeta^j=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x-\zeta^j)f(x)}{x^N-1}
=\frac{\zeta f(\zeta^j)}N.$$
Putting $\zeta^j$ into $f(x)=\sum\overline{\chi}(m)x^m$
will give you something that's basically a Gauss sum.